# Create AMI without manually specifying BlockDeviceMappings

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

Is there a way to register an image (AMI) with all its storage without having to manually specify everything in `BlockDeviceMappings`?

Here's an example, generating an AMI with Python/Boto3:

```
ami = ec2.register_image(
    Name='Test Image',
    Description='Automatic AMI',
    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'SnapshotId': 'snapshotId',
                'VolumeSize': 30,
                'VolumeType': 'gp2'
            }
        },
        {
            'DeviceName': 'xvdf',
            'Ebs': {
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'SnapshotId': 'snapshotId',
                'VolumeSize': 30,
                'VolumeType': 'gp3'
            }
        }
    ],
    Architecture='x86_64',
    RootDeviceName='/dev/sda1',
    DryRun=False,
    VirtualizationType='hvm',
    EnaSupport=True
)
```

Right now, I have to specify snapshots, volume size, types, etc.

I'd like to do as I can do via the GUI and just *specify an instance* so that no matter how many storage is attached to that instance, all of them would be attached to the generated AMI?

What I thought is: fetch the instance ID, fetch all volumes attached to that instance and store them in an array, loop through them and generate the `BlockDeviceMappings` array but I feel like there's a more straightforward way of doing so.

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [`create_image`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=ec2#EC2.Client.create_image) instead of `register_image`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you!